# How does google voice get routed?

Tags: android, google-voice

I understand that GoogleVoice is effectively a broker between a caller and reciepient; but when does GoogleVoice use VOIP and when does it use traditional connection?

There is a number(?) of scenarios I can deduce:
**PC-PC**:  VOIP for sure

Can someone help me with the scenarios below:
1) real cell phone that has GoogleVoice app installed.  Calling out of GoogleVoice app to non-GoogleVoice number... is it VOIP or not?
2) real cell phone that has GoogleVoice app installed.  Calling out of GoogleVoice app to GoogleVoice number... is it VOIP or not?
3) real phone calling to GoogleVoice number that is linked to (not ported to) the real phone having a GoogleVoice app.  
4) real phone calling to GoogleVoice number that is not linked to (not ported to) the real phone having a GoogleVoice app.  In this case the voicemail would kick in

Comment: Leaning toward not programming related. Did you at least look at the [documentation/help topics](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/7649189?hl=en&ref_topic=1708123) *and select the appropriate device tab*?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I absolutely agree: this is not programming related at all.   This is general concept that is driven by some programming implementation.  However, I am not soliciting anything progrmaming-wise.  Just want to know in general how it works.  I figured some of the programmers here must be in the know.